# Add audio clip via VBA to PowerPoint Presentation that spans multiple slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

To play an audio clip inserted as a shape across multiple slides in a presentation, there is an option in the **Play Sound** dialog in the **Effect** tab called **Stop playing** and this can be set to **After __ slides**.

I've browsed the object model and even attempted recording a macro using ppt 2003 (the option does not record).  How (if it can) can this option be set via **VBA**?

[image: Stop Playing After __ slides option]

The way I'm currently adding a sound (that stops after the slides are advanced) is:

```
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oEffect As Effect

Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)

Set oShp = oSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject("C:\MyAudioClip.wav", True, False, 10, 10)

Set oEffect = oSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(oShp, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
oEffect.MoveTo 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oEffect As Effect

Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set oShp = oSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject("p:\testfile\media\minivincent.wav", True, False, 10, 10)

With oShp.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings
    .PlayOnEntry = True
    .PauseAnimation = False
    .StopAfterSlides = 19
End With
```