# Adding audio file to PowerPoint presentation using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I can open an instance of powerpoint from excel vba, insert text in a textbox on a slide and apply animation on it. 
I have an audio file (.wav) which I intend to add on the slide. I can do it manually but how do I do it using excel vba?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflo w Larry. Check this answer to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986507/add-audio-clip-via-vba-to-powerpoint-presentation-that-spans-multiple-slides If not, post what you've got so far and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Shamala Larry Are you asking for programming help? Have you some code to show so it can be improved?

Comment: @P5music whenever I try to insert code in the body section, I can't post my question coz I am told that my code isn't in the correct format.

Comment: I later found the solution to the problem. This conversation can be closed